# Cannot render a Partial view from JavaScript in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

On get response i want to render a partial view using javascript.this is my coffeescript file.
`scrolls.coffee`

```
$.getJSON('/scrolls/output.json',{name: value}).done (data,status,e) ->
    $("#show_output").append("<% escape_javascript( render partial: 'scrolls/output') %>")
```

Instead it is just showing plain text inside the append that is this is the output.

```
<% escape_javascript( render partial: 'scrolls/output') %>
```

Why my ruby code is not executing in coffeescript.I used `coffee.erb`.extention too.Same output.My rails version`4.2.4`

Comment: Did you try using <%= instead of <%? <% will process the input but won't show it in the template file. And also try to rename the file to scrolls.coffee.erb.

Comment: @lavilet i tried `<%` and `<%=`.I also tried with the file extension `.js.erb`,`js.coffee`,`js.coffee.erb`,`coffee`.Ruby is never executed and never worked in all these file types.

Answer (score -1):

Try using "#{escape_javascript(render partial: 'scrolls/output') }", instead of <% %>.